# ¿Es posible desde una aplicacion de consola en dev c++ crear un archivo de excel y ingresarle datos?

Tags: c++, dev-c++

Es posible que en una aplicación de consola desde dev c++ se pueda crear un archivo de excel con datos ingresados desde ahi, y si es posible como podría hacerse? tengo entendido que se puede crear archivos txt y ingresarle datos desde c++, lo cual ya he hecho y les compartire el codigo de este, pero desde c++ crear un archivo de excel y ingresarle los datos desde ahi es posible?

les adjunto mi codigo para crear un archivo txt y ingresarle datos desde c++

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;

void escribirFrases();

int main(){
escribirFrases();

system("pause");
return 0;
} 

void escribirFrases(){
ofstream archivo;
string nombreArchivo,frase;
char rpt;

cout<<"Digite el nombre del archivo: ";
getline(cin,nombreArchivo);

archivo.open(nombreArchivo.c_str(),ios::out); //Creamos el archivo

if(archivo.fail()){ //Si a ocurrido algun error
    cout<<"No se pudo abrir el archivo";
    exit(1);
}

do{
    fflush(stdin);
    cout<<"Digite una frase: ";
    getline(cin,frase);
    archivo<<frase<<endl;

    cout<<"\nDesea agregar otra frase(S/N): ";
    cin>>rpt;
}while((rpt == 'S') || (rpt == 's'));

archivo.close(); //Cerramos el archivo
}
```

Comment: Buscas como hacer un .csv?

Comment: Si, lo mismo que hice con el archivo .txt pero creando un excel o un csv como comentas tu

Answer (score 1):

> ¿Es posible que en una aplicación de consola desde dev c++ se pueda crear un archivo de excel con datos ingresados desde ahí?, y si es posible ¿Cómo podría hacerse?

Dependerá de la versión de Excel para la que quieras hacer el archivo, pero poderse: se puede hacer. Tan sólo ten en cuenta que deberás escribir en el formato que Excel espera; Microsoft tiene una página dedicada a explicar ese formato (traducción mía):

> #### [Entendiendo el Formato de archivo Binario Excel .xls](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg615597(v=office.14).aspx)
>
> La [Especificación de Estructura del Formato de Archivo Binario [MS-XLS] (.xls)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc313154(v=office.14).aspx) es usada por Microsoft Office Excel 2003, Microsoft Excel 2002, Microsoft Escel 2000 y Microsoft Excel 97. El formato está organicado en conjuntos y subconjuntos. Cada pestaña de la hoja de cálculo se guarda en su subconjunto. Todos los datos se contienen en registros que tienen cabeceras, que determinan el tipo del registro y su longitud. Los registros de Celdas, que contienen tanto la celda en si como las fórmulas y propiedades de celda, residen en la tabla de celdas. Los valores de cadena de caracteres no se almacenan en el registro de celda si no en una tabla de cadenas de caracteres compartidas, que los registros de celda referencian. Los registros de Fila cintienen informaciónde propiedades para una fila y localizaciones de celda. Sólo las celdas que contienen datos o formato individual se almacenan en el subconjunto.

En el [enlace de la especificación](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc313154(v=office.14).aspx) tienes todos los detalles del formato. En cuanto a cómo usarlo desde C++, tendrás que usar (como ya usas en tu ejemplo) `std::ofstream` pero [configurado en modo binario](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/openmode) (no texto) y seguir la especificación para aquello que necesites.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta paula, voy a mirar como me va, solo que de ese tema no se encuentra mucha informacion disponible, o videos ejemplo donde muestren como crean un archivo de excel o un csv desde una aplicacion de consola en c++, la informacion que hay lo hacen es a un txt asi como esta en mi codigo, pero no he visto en concreto que alguien lo haga con un excel o csv.

Comment: Me parece que no tienes muy claro lo que es un archivo [csv](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valores_separados_por_comas). Un csv es un archivo de texto en crudo que Excel puede interpretar como una tabla; evidentemente, por ello carecerá de formato y características específicas de Excel. Cada uno de los valores del archivo está separado por comas y Excel interpretará que cada valor debe ser alojado en una celda.